# Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância - Chave Estrangeira Nula

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Senhores(as),

Tenho um relacionamento entre duas tabelas, Funcionário e Documentos (1 : N)

No meu sistema existem duas etapas:
1° - A recepcionista cadastra com informações básicas um documento que chega na instituição e dispara um e-mail para o responsável realizar a retirada desses.

2° - A secretária valida esses documentos incluindo informações complementares, incluindo o e-mail do funcionário (userId) e fazendo alterações caso seja necessário

Acontece que quando a recepcionista faz o primeiro cadastro desse documento no sistema, o campo “UserId” está nulo, para que assim, a secretária determine para quem vai cada um desses documentos.

Essa é a view que está dando problemas:

```
<table class="table table-bordered data-table" style="font-size: 12px">
    <tr>
        <th>Remetente</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DocumentoTipoId)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DataRecebimentoRecepcao)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DataRecebimentoSecretaria)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Observacao)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.UserId)</th>
        <th>Ação</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var docs in Model.Documentos) {
        var dataRec = docs.DataRecebimentoRecepcao.HasValue ? docs.DataRecebimentoRecepcao.Value.ToString() : "";
        var dataSec = docs.DataRecebimentoSecretaria.HasValue ? docs.DataRecebimentoSecretaria.Value.ToString() : "";
        <tr>
            <td>@docs.Remetente</td>
            <td>@docs.DocumentoTipo.Tipo</td>
            <td>@dataRec</td>
            <td>@dataSec</td>
            <td>@docs.Observacao</td>
            <td>@docs.UserProfileV.UserName</td> @*O ERRO ESTÁ NESTA LINHA*@

            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" title="Editar Documento"
                        onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("ValidarDocumento", new { id = MyCrypto.Encrypt(docs.DocumentoId.ToString()) })'">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

**model Documento**

```
 public class Documento {

    public int DocumentoId { get; set; }
    public string Remetente { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataRecebimentoRecepcao { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DataRecebimentoSecretaria { get; set; }
    public bool Retirado { get; set; }
    public string Observacao { get; set; }

    // Relacionamento 1:N

    public int DocumentoTipoId { get; set; }
    public virtual DocumentoTipo DocumentoTipo { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfileContext UserProfileV { get; set; }
}
```

**Model Funcionário**

```
    public class UserProfileContext {
    public UserProfileContext() {
        this.DadosComplementares = new List<DadosComplementares>();
        this.webpages_Roles = new List<webpages_Roles>();
        this.Chamados = new List<ChamadoContext>();
        this.Interessados = new List<InteressadosContext>();
        this.Tecnicos = new List<TecnicoContext>();
        this.Documentos = new List<Documento>();
        //this.DocumentosFuncionarios = new List<DocumentoFuncionario>();

    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ChamadoContext> Chamados { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ChamadosMkt> ChamadosMkt { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DadosComplementares> DadosComplementares { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<webpages_Roles> webpages_Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<InteressadosContext> Interessados { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TecnicoContext> Tecnicos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TecnicoMkt> TecnicosMkt { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<InteressadosMkt> InteressadosMkt { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Gestores> Gestores { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ControleChaves> ControleChaves { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Documento> Documentos { get; set; }
}
```

Eu já tentei deixar no banco o “UserId” aceitar nulo
já tentei fazer verificações na própria view se o objeto está nulo e mostrar um campo vazio
Já tentei incluir Try Catch NullException e mostrar uma mensagem informando que o campo email é obrigatório, mas sempre… SEMPRE retorna este erro… Simplesmente não sei mais o que faço.

Obrigado a todos que me ajudarem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Tente a seguinte verificação na sua `View`, fiz uma verificação em duas etapas, primeiro confirma se o objeto está nulo e depois o UserName

```
<table class="table table-bordered data-table" style="font-size: 12px">
    <tr>
        <th>Remetente</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DocumentoTipoId)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DataRecebimentoRecepcao)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.DataRecebimentoSecretaria)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Observacao)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.UserId)</th>
        <th>Ação</th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var docs in Model.Documentos) {
        var dataRec = docs.DataRecebimentoRecepcao.HasValue ? docs.DataRecebimentoRecepcao.Value.ToString() : "";
        var dataSec = docs.DataRecebimentoSecretaria.HasValue ? docs.DataRecebimentoSecretaria.Value.ToString() : "";
        <tr>
            <td>@docs.Remetente</td>
            <td>@docs.DocumentoTipo.Tipo</td>
            <td>@dataRec</td>
            <td>@dataSec</td>
            <td>@docs.Observacao</td>
            <td>
                @if(docs.UserProfileV != null && docs.UserProfileV.UserName!= null)
                {
                    <label>
                        @docs.UserProfileV.UserName
                    </label>
                }
            </td> 

            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" title="Editar Documento"
                        onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("ValidarDocumento", new { id = MyCrypto.Encrypt(docs.DocumentoId.ToString()) })'">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Consegui aqui

Comment: @PedroBaraldini Se essa resposta te ajudou, [marque ela como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Caso você tenha conseguido de outra forma, publique sua resposta e marque ela como aceita. Se não fizer isso sua pergunta fica aberta no site ;)